# Cannot import Swagger 2.0 into API Manager with parameter reference

Tags: import, integration, swagger, ibm-cloud, swagger-2.0

When I try to import a Swagger 2.0 file into the [API Manager](https://apim.ibmcloud.com/apimanager) with a parameter reference, I get the following error:

> Could not process the API request. See
>   the server log for more information,
>   or contact your administrator.

The Swagger definition looks like this:

```js
{
    ...
    "parameters": {
        "p": {
            "name": "p",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Parameter",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "default": "x"
        }
    },
    "paths": {
        "/stuff": {
            "get": {
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/parameters/p"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Success",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/result"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I specify the parameter directly, import succeeds:

```js
{
    ...
    "paths": {
        "/stuff": {
            "get": {
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "p",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "Parameter",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "x"
                    }
                ],
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why does it fail? Is this unsupported or a bug, or am I missing something?

Is there a way for me to see the server log to get more details on the failure, as stated in the error message?

Comment: We are checking with the team that owns that now...

Answer (score 1):

As of version 4000, API Management does not currently support parameter references, but you should not get a 500 response - you should instead get an appropriate 400 error message.  I'll reach out to the team to log a defect against the product.

Comment: It would be nice to get more informative messages than just the _"Could not process the API request"_ to help with debugging. In particular, we are also receiving this message when we have many routes in a big Swagger definition file with hundreds of KB to over 1 MB. It should be noted that it e.g. breaks with just one more path item parameter, or one more path item that is basically the same as the previous but a different name (which should therefore work).